# Add stuff to wp_head from template file

Tags: php, wordpress, header, hook

I tried to add some stuff to the Wordpress header with the wp_header hook but this does not work.
The stuff what I want to add is specific to that file what is loaded by `get_template_part`

The code that I tried below

```
add_action('wp_head', 'to_head');

function to_head(){
        echo 'jojo';
}
```

What I also tried is the code below because these hook running earlier the the wp_head hook

```
add_action('get_header', 'to_head');

function to_head(){
        echo 'jojo';
}
```

Both code does not work.

Please who can help me with this? It cant be you can only use the hooks on functions.php right?

[image: functions.php]

[image: Output]

Comment: Where are you putting this code?

Comment: @Bhautik I placed this code on a template file that is included by the function **get_template_part** the stuf what I want set in de header is specific for this template part.

Comment: Try to put the above code in the functions.php file.

Comment: In the functions.php the code respons the stuff to the body tag and not to the head tag

Comment: which snippet did you use from above?

Comment: I tried both hooks.

Comment: this `add_action('wp_head', 'to_head');` hooks should work. can put some screenshots to question?

Comment: @Bhautik I added screenshots to my question

Comment: I tested and works fine for me.